# Can we call G-d our mother?

Tags: halacha, commentaries

Today it’s [Mother's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Day), which made me wonder if I could call G-d mother? Because G-d ‘gave life’ to all things. Of course we call him Aba, but why not Ima?

Comment: "Of course we call him Aba": citation needed.

Comment: fyi - I cannot think of an example where G-d is referred to as a mother.

Comment: @msh210 e.g. 'Avinu malkeinu'

Comment: Schina is gd an is definitely seen as feminine. So yeh

Answer (score 2):

Why not?  God calls *us*, Israel, His "mother":

> Listen to Me, My people; and give ear to Me, O My mother... [Isaiah 51:4]

The Midrash adds how this struck bar Yochai as supremely significant:

> [Rabbi Eleazar said:] The Holy One, blessed be He, first addressed Israel as “daughter” [then “sister”, then “mother”.] [As “daughter”,] in "Hearken, O daughter, consider and incline your ear…" [Ps. 45:11] As "sister” in "Open to me, my sister, my love, my dove, my undefiled... [Song of Songs 5:2]  And when He loved Israel even more, He called them “mother”, for it says [see Isaiah, above]. Rabbi Shim’on bar Yohai arose and kissed [Rabbi Elazar] on his forehead [saying]... “If this had been the only thing I learned in life, I would have been satisfied.” [Exodus Rabbah 52:5]

These passages show that "mother" is a flexible appellation, not always literal. God has many masculine names, but also a feminine one, the Shechinah.

Comment: With respect I'm not sure this answers the question?

Comment: It shows that "mother" is a flexible appellation, not always literal.  God has many masculine names, but also a feminine one, the Shechinah.

Comment: Yes but you are showing that Hashem calls us mother and not the other way round?

Comment: The question was "can you say", not "where does it say".

Comment: Agreed but by showing that Hashem calls the yidden mother does not prove that we can call Him mother?

Comment: Yes, the shekhinah is the feminine aspect of G-d (but this is a mystic idea). The shekhinah actually means the presence of G-d. Onkelos says that the shekhinah is a human feeling of G-d. As for the names of G-d, G-d does not have a name. Overall, I agree with your answer.

Comment: Also,  Maimonides views the idea that Shekhinah is a female version of G-d as avodah zarah (idolatry).

Comment: I agree with previous comments, this *bichlal* does not answer the question. Regardless that *kabalistically* the *shechinah* may be construed as feminine, the fact that Hashem is not referred to as "mother" anywhere in *tenach*, *shas* or medrash indicates that indeed we do not refer to Hashem as such.

Comment: I am not knowledgeable enough so please consult a Rabbi before taking anything I post at face value, but since no one has mentioned this yet I will do my best. My understanding is that the Shechinah is seen as feminine because it receives from the masculine aspect. I've also read that Hashem is all "right" at the highest level. It doesnt mean His essence is gendered necessarily but kabbalistically the right pillar is the masculine and the left is the feminine. By calling Hashem "Mother" it might be confusing the receiving aspect of Him with the whole. But that raises question why "He" is OK.

Comment: It's difficult to explain but essentially as stated in the answer furthest down the page, if we want to call to G-d as the source of everything, then the seed is what goes into the womb, ergo "He." However everything is in G-d, He's not limited by time, so can you really say the seed came before the womb, or goes into the womb *first* or does the seed contain the womb and vice versa at the level of G-d since He is beyond opposites. But if you *do* gender G-d then the Father is what puts the seed of life in the Mother, so I think thats the distinction why "He" is used.

Comment: Now for a question. What's the explanation of Israel being the mother of G-d? Chabad.org translates it as, "Hearken to Me, My people, and My nation, bend your ears to Me, when Torah shall emanate from Me, and My judgment [shall be] for the light of the peoples, I will give [them] rest." 

Sefaria translation: "Hearken to Me, My people,
And give ear to Me, O My nation..."

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any halakha that would say no. The shekhinah is considered by many to be the feminine aspect of G-d. We could figuratively call G-d mother, but we must remember that G-d has no gender. G-d is neither He nor She (Rambam).

Comment: thanks for the answer. Where is this Rambam located please?

Comment: @Dovid according to Maimonides G-d is not male or female.  Maimonides views the concept to say G-d is a gender as avodah zarah (idolatry). See Rambam's theory of negative attributes or apopathic theology which says that we may only describe what G-d is not.

Comment: But where is the Rambam? Sorry if you already said I just don't see it.

Comment: @Dovid I forget but I will try to look for it.

Answer (score -1):

I do not claim to understand the following, I only quote what I’ve seen. In Sefer Sifsei Chein hakdama 9 he explains that the sefira of Bina is referred to in the zohar as אם and also corresponds to our foremother Leah. The sefira of Malchus corresponds to our foremother Rachel. Malchus gathers all of the influence from the higher sefiros and pours the shefa (influence) onto man manifesting the influence from above. Similarly a mother receives the seed of a man, cultivates it and manifests that influence to create a child.

So we see that some of G-d's attributes are referred to in the Zohar as אם and are associated with our אימהות. These are reasons to allow us to refer to G-d as אם.

Comment: You need to explain how what you have written is an answer to the question, "Can we call G-d our Mother?"

Comment: “He” is directly referred to as אם in the zohar (or at least some of his attributes are) and is associated with our אימהות. Thus I think that is grounds to refer to him as אם.

Comment: Following your comment, I have expressed your answer explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a two-part question. Asking whether we can call G-d "mother," and why is G-d referred to as the father.

I read Jordan Peterson's book [12 rules for life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345816021). In the book, Peterson explained why many cultures, including the Bible, described G-d in masculine terms. He used the example of the Yin and Yang. The Yang is the masculine side, associated with light. The Yin is the feminine, negative dark side. Although women give birth men are seen as the giver of life, order. This is not anti-women, just the representations of dark and light in ancient cultures. The Bible does the same. Since G-d "spoke" order into the universe, He is described as masculine. We look up to the father. It is psychological.

Now that we know the origins and reasons for calling G-d Aba, we could call G-d Ima so long as we recognize that He is neither male nor female, “the Torah speaks in human language" (Rambam).

Comment: The Torah view is definitely not what Peterson, as you represent him, says. I am unfamiliar with his book. But like is said explicitly in the Torah, male and female were both equal sources of light. The feminine was reduced voluntarily so as not to appear like a representation of there being 2 G-ds. The primary quality of the feminine according to the Torah view is conversion from one state to another. This is the principle of teshuvah, like the thread of the Alter converting from red to white on Yom Kippur.

Comment: @YaacovDeane That's interesting. Did you read the Peterson book? He seems to say that ancient cultures understood the male aspect of G-d as order the female as chaos. This seems to make sense. Do you agree with it?

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, I don’t know Peterson and have never heard of his book. Regarding your chaos idea being feminine/female, that is not the traditional Torah viewpoint. That is likely one of the distortions that happened early on following the generation of Enosh. Rambam discusses this evolution of religious thought and how it gradually diverged from the original accurate teachings about G-d in Mishneh Torah, Laws of Avodah Zarah, chapter 1.

Comment: The idea about female chaos is very ingrained in Torah, especially the Garden of Eden story.

Comment: You should try to explain that to a Jewish woman and see how it goes for you. 

Comment: @YaacovDeane I respect all women. We do not know why the ancients chose to represent the giver of life with chaos. We can only say they chose to respent order as masculine maybe because the males were dominant in running society. This is why G-d(s) are always referred to as "He." G-d "spoke" order into the chaos world.

Comment: Genesis 1:2: “Now the earth was tohu vavohu and darkness was upon the face of the tehom and the ruach elohim hovered over the face of the waters.” No one really knows what tohu vavohu means, but it could mean unformed or unfashioned matter. Similarly, many Jewish day prayers thank G-d for not being a woman. This should not be seen as anti-female but in a psychological sense, in terms of the ancients. The Torah was written in the language of men.

Comment: For example, Eve is the one who brings chaos to the universe by eating the apple, not Adam.

Comment: With B'reshit bara Elohim, the verb bara (he created) is a masculine term.

Comment: @TurkHill With all due respect, but Eve wasn’t the one who did that, one could say more or the less that the ‘human being’ did it; for neither Chava nor Adam heeded what the Almighty had told them. They all pointed finger at each other and none of them repented. And Chava and Adam both had to bear the consequences of their choices/deeds.

Comment: Besides I don’t the they wanted to bring Chaos deliberately into this world, but rather this was the result/consequence of their deed. People shouldn’t just put ‘the blame’ on Chava and pretend that Adam had no part in it, for both took of the fruit of the tree that was forbidden them, both ate of it, and again both disobeyed the direct words of the Almighty who had told them not to do such a thing. Although it would be nice to blame my wife for everything, don’t I have to take my own responsibility, make my own choices or at least tell her she’s wrong instead of going along?

Comment: @Levi Thank you for sharing your thinking and comments. I agree with you. I wrote in my answer that according to Jordan Peterson, ancient cultures usually represented the female sex as chaos and the male as order. For example, the Yin is the feminine aspect and represents chaos while the Yang is male and represents order and masculinity, in the Yin/Yang. We do not know why the ancients chose these sexes to represent their fears and hopes. Perhaps it has something to do with the male sex being the driver of civilization.

Comment: Nevertheless, this seems to help explain why G-d is referred to as "HE" (although G-d has no gender) in Scripture. For example, G-d brings order into the universe and this helps explain why Eve is the recipient of chaos when she eats the apple from the tree of good and evil. From a historical, cultural point of view, this makes sense.

Comment: My own personal opinion is that I agree with you. Clearly, Adam ate from the apple after Eve. The person in the get-away car is just as guilty as the robber for he also participated in the robbery. Personally, I am a fan of Rambam and take the rationalist approach that G-d did not speak anything during creation. This was G-d's thoughts and that the Garden of Eve story may be a parable (Rambam and Ralbag).

Comment: There might have been an Eve, but the idea to blame Eve for all the problems of the world would be mistaken, let alone highly offensive to women. I respect all women and they have the same rights as men.